# Rails: Order by associate, first not downloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, associate

I have a problem displaying files accessible via my application. When a user logs in, I want to display all of their files. Files downloaded by current user should be displayed last. The file table has about 500 records, so I need simple and fast method to achieve this.

```
class User
  has_many :downloads
  has_many :downloaded_files, :through => :downloads, source: :file
end

class File 
  attr_accessor :downloaded

  has_many :downloads
  has_many :users, :through => :downloads
end

class Download
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :file
end
```

The technologies I am using

- Rails 4.2.1
- Ruby 2.2.2
- PostgreSQL

Comment: What do you mean by all of **their** files? When do you consider that file belongs to user?

Comment: All upload files (few files don't have any users). Now i am using in files_controller.rb - `current_user.downloaded_files` for show only downloaded files by current user or `current_user.downloaded_files.include?(self)` for an single file.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more simple way to do such thing using my [Where Exists](https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists) gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I see no need to over-think this issue. Five hundred records is nothing in terms of DB load, so just fire off two queries:

**Your controller's code**

```
# Current user files
@user_files = current_user.downloaded_files

# Select all files which don't have Download record for current user
@other_files = File.where("NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM downloads WHERE file_id = files.id AND user_id = ?)", current_user.id)
```

Then just use @user_files and @other_files in your view one after another. Something like

**Your view's code**

```
<%= render partial: 'files', collection: @other_files %>
<%= render partial: 'files', collection: @user_files %>
```

**UPD**

Using [Where Exists](https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists) gem (disclosure: I've released it recently) you can simplify your controller code.

Instead of this:

```
@other_files = File.where("NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM downloads WHERE file_id = files.id AND user_id = ?)", current_user.id)
```

You can write this:

```
@other_files = File.where_not_exists(:downloads, user_id: current_user.id)
```